# file manipulation and find a word and tricky replace

Tags: python, file, replace

I have file something like this

```
hostname ser1-xyz
myuser   name
passwd   secret
group    1234

hostname ser2-xyz
myuser   name
passwd   secret
group    2345
```

I need to find the line first appearance of host named "ser1-xyz" and modify it as 
"ser1" and increment it's the group value by 1

So that final file looks like :

```
hostname ser1
myuser   name
passwd   secret
group    1235

hostname ser2-xyz
myuser   name
passwd   secret
group    2345
```

Currently I'm following code,which can modify the "ser1-xyz" into "ser1"

```
        for line in fileinput.FileInput(fn,inplace=1):
                line = line.replace(search,replace)
```

But how to increment group value?

Comment: Are you able to change the format of the file? This looks to be providing a similar function to the /etc/passwd file. In the passwd file each record is on a single line and the fields are colon separated. This will make it a lot easier to manipulate.

Comment: No , I can't change file format. That's how I receive this file. Thanks for query, following code worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way

```
import fileinput
f=0
for line in fileinput.input("file",inplace=0):
    if "hostname" in line and "ser1-xyz" in line:
       line=line.replace("ser1-xyz","ser1")
       f=1
    if f and "group" in line:
       a=line.rstrip().split(" ")
       a[-1]=str(int(a[-1])+1)
       line=' '.join(a)
       f=0
    print line.rstrip()
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
hostname ser1
myuser   name
passwd   secret
group    1235

hostname ser2-xyz
myuser   name
passwd   secret
group    2345
```

change `inplace=0` to `inplace=1` for inplace edit.